# Spark - Simple GraphX program taking long time to complete

Tags: apache-spark, emr, spark-graphx

I have a 9 node m3.xlarge (8 cpu / 15 gig) EMR cluster, where 1 node is the master and other 8 are slaves. I'm trying to run a simple program to check GraphX connected components. This is my code:

```
def main(args : Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
      .set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
      .set("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
      .set("hive.s3.max-client-retries", "50")
      .set("hive.s3.max-error-retries", "50")
      .set("hive.s3.max-connections", "100")
      .set("hive.s3.connect-timeout", "5m")
      .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "true")
      .set("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.VertexAttributeBlock")
      .set("spark.broadcast.compress", "true")
      .set("spark.default.parallelism", "24")

     val spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("Spark Hive Example")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .config(sparkConfig)
        .getOrCreate()

    // Set Kryo for serializing
    GraphXUtils.registerKryoClasses(sparkConfig)
    val res = spark.sql("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 limit 10000")
    val edgesRDD = res.rdd.map(row => Edge(row.getString(0).hashCode, row.getString(1).hashCode, row(2).asInstanceOf[String]))

    val res_two = spark.sql("SELECT col1 FROM table2 where col1 is not NULL and col1 != '' limit 100000")
    val vertexRDD: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = res_two.rdd.map(row => (row.getString(0).hashCode, row(0).asInstanceOf[String]))

    val graph = Graph(vertexRDD, edgesRDD)
    graph.cache()

    val connectedComponents = graph.connectedComponents().vertices
```

I submit the jar on the EMR cluster using:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=xxx --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=xxx --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false --class com.mypkg.SampleGraphX --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --num-executors 12 --executor-cores 6 --executor-memory 10g --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize=1000 -Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheTimeout=60" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheSize=1000 -Djavax.net.ssl.sessionCacheTimeout=60" GraphxTest1.jar
```

Both table1 and table2 have millions of entries, but I have limited my code to read only 10000 and 100000 entries from them. Both are external tables located on S3. This job has been running for almost 2 days now. Why is it taking such a long time? Is there something wrong with my code? Or do I need to change some configuration?

Also, when I look at the UI, I see that even though my cluster has 64 vCores (8 cores per node), each node is using only 1 core.
In the image below, only 3 cores of the total 64 are being used. I have seen this go to a maximum of 6 cores (when 6 nodes were active). Why isn't it using all of the cores?

I'm new to both Spark and GraphX, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking at the Spark UI, this is the scheduler UI. You should find your application in the list, and access to the URL linked to your application.
When you access Spark UI, it will be much easier to tell what's happening (not enough memory in Storage, not enough partitions, stuck in reading data, stuck in an iteration...)

Comment: This is what the log says:
`17/08/22 23:17:48 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_1502391082530_0027_01_000007 on host: .... Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1502391082530_0027_01_000007
Exit code: 1
...

Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1`. Is it some config issue? Am I using too much memory?